# dependency injection in asp.net core with generic parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I am getting the following error during usage of service collection:

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> HappinessMeter.BL.GenericBL.IGenericBL'1[HappinessMeter.Entity.Models.MCountry]
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationInstance:
> HappinessMeter.BL.EFCoreCountryBL': Constant value of type
> 'HappinessMeter.BL.EFCoreCountryBL' can't be converted to service type
> 'HappinessMeter.BL.GenericBL.IGenericBL`1[HappinessMeter.Entity.Models.MCountry]'

in `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IGenericBL<MCountry>), 
  new EFCoreCountryBL(new EFCoreCountryRepository(context))));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IGenericBL<User>),  
   new EFCoreUserBL(new EFCoreUserRepository(context))));
```

my code is for EFCoreRepository is :

```
public class EFCoreRepository<Tentity, Tcontext> : IRepository<Tentity> where Tentity : class where Tcontext : DbContext
    {
        public readonly Tcontext context;
        public EFCoreRepository(Tcontext _context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }
        public async Task<Tentity> Add(Tentity entity)
        {
            context.Set<Tentity>().Add(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<Tentity> Delete(long id)
        {
            var entity = await context.Set<Tentity>().FindAsync(id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return entity;
            }

            context.Set<Tentity>().Remove(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<Tentity> Get(long id) => await context.Set<Tentity>().FindAsync(id);

        public async Task<List<Tentity>> GetAll() => await context.Set<Tentity>().ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Tentity> Update(Tentity entity)
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

and EFCoreCountryRepository is

```
public class EFCoreCountryRepository : EFCoreRepository<MCountry, HMDEVContext>
    {
        public EFCoreCountryRepository(HMDEVContext context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        public async Task<MCountry> GetByAlpha(string alpha)
        {
            return await  context.MCountry.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Alpha2Code == alpha);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code for `EFCoreCountryRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

error says: `EFCoreCountryBL` can't be converted to `IGenericBL1<MCountry>`

you either have type mismatch or missing implicit or explicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks, but i have problem with code 
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IGenericBL<>),typeof(GenericBL<>))); how can i use generic classes from here